# bash variable forward declaration

Tags: bash, global-variables

Let's say I have a script with a bunch of constants set at the beginning, which I ordered alphabetically for better overview:

```
declare -r home_folder=/home/
declare -r user_folder=$home_folder$user_name/
declare -r user_name=$USER
```

Obviously, the evaluation of the second line will not give the result that one might expect on the first look, since bash does the evaluation only once, and thus later calls to `$user_folder` will still just give `/home/`. Is there any way to overcome this?

EDIT: A preferred solution would look like

```
declare -r home_folder=/home/
declare -r user_folder=$home_folder$pointer-to-user_name/
declare -r user_name=$USER
```

with the pointer being evaluated when `user_folder` is evaluated but I do not know if it is possible to this in bash.

Comment: ALPHABETICALLY ???? How about ordering them semantically, then probably your problem goes away by itself.   (Alphabetically … *unbelieving head shake*)  No hard feelings, please.  My proposal:  Try ordering them in the order in which they "appear", then this problem goes away.  Ordering them alphabetically does not have enough advantages (none, if you ask me) to justify this.

Comment: Shell scripting is an iterative way to express behavior, the order of execution is not dependency-based.  What you want to achieve requires either reading through all potential assignments and only executing those for which dependencies are met until all assignments have been performed or all those left have unmet dependencies, or building some kind of dependency tree and following it.  You can build that or, more probably, decide that ordering assignments based on their semantics actually makes sense and helps avoiding cyclic dependencies, especially if using `set -u`.

Comment: The name of the command aside, there are no actual variable declarations in shell. `declare -r user_name` only sets an attribute on a *name*; `user_name` is still undefined until you actually assign a value to it. (OK, `-r` is a bad example, because failing to assign to a name you are marking as read-only effectively prevents you from ever defining a variable by that name.)

Comment: @Alfe I'm not going to enter this religious war about who has the "right" conventions. Can we live in peace if I tell you that it is just set up like this to make for a simple example?

Comment: @chepner Could you provide a bit more explanation or a link, please? I think I don't really get it yet.

Comment: I don't see religions involved here.  However, I know no way of allowing such arbitrary order of declarations in `bash` as it is interpreted and executed line by line.  You could probably replace all your variables (constants) by shell functions which may or may not rely on other shell functions.  These are executed on usage, not on declaration.  But this will massively blow up your code.

Comment: @N.Nord Try this: `declare foo; [[ -v foo ]] && echo "foo is set"`. You should get no output, because the variable `foo` does not exist. Then run `foo=; [[ -v foo ]] && echo "foo is set"`, which should produce output because you have created the variable by assigning a value (the empty string, but still, a value) to the name.

Comment: @Fred I thought more on a possibility to include pointers into the variables which are evaluated once I check the value of the variable instead of building a dependency-based evaluation order, but I will have a look at `set`.

Comment: I am wondering what is the value of using -r at all if you know you wish the variables to receive altered values at some other point.  As others have advised, bash is executed from top to bottom, so you need to name your variables in the order they will be applied for following lines.  Maybe you need to explain what your reasoning is for using this format / idea?

Comment: @grail I don't want my variables to receive altered values and I know that bash evaluates the code from top to bottom. Therefore I was asking this question. The reasoning is, that larger sets of variables make maintenance difficult, because one has to manually check all the order dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The bash script is executed line by line from top to bottom as it’s only logical. Same with plenty of other programming languages. A variable always contains the value you assigned to it earlier.

Maybe I do not understand what do you mean by "forward declaration". Or you mix "assignment" with "declaration"?

Comment: Not sure if I'm mixing it up... what I want be able to do is something like `a=pointer_to_b` and `b=foo` so if I write `$a` I get `foo`.

Comment: There are no pointers in bash afaik. There may be other ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. You could try eval: a='$b'; b=foo; eval echo $a; c='eval echo $a'; $c

Comment: Or a='eval $b'; b=echo; $a – but you won’t be able to use it like real pointers

Comment: Looks interesting, but the behavior differs to much from that of a normal variable, for example in case one writes echo `$a`.

Comment: Expansion in bash differs often from what you would expect ("$@" vs "$*" for instance). There are subtle differences between strong and week quoting – you should have a look at that – There are some good scripting guides available

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all variables by shell functions:

```
home_folder() { echo "/home/"; }
user_folder() { echo "$(home_folder)$(user_name)/"; }
user_name() { echo "$USER"; }
```

Then in your using code you could always write `$(xxx)` to access the contents of `xxx` (instead of the usual `$xxx` or `${xxx}`).

But this will slow down everything because each value will always be re-created upon being used.  Maybe you can live with this.

Comment: Probably the best bet as of now, but I'm not sure I want to write code like this... Is there no way like `a=pointer_to_b` and `b=foo` so if I write `$a` I get `foo`?

Comment: Well, what you look for is a feature of non-script languages which get compiled prior to execution. In these it is typical for each constant within its scope to have exactly one value.  Contradicting assignments are found and rejected by the compiler then.  In scripting contexts this is handled differently.  You can overwrite the value holders as often as you like.  Only the current values are taken into account.  So referring to a not-yet set value results not in any lookup but in either a runtime error or (as in bash) a default value like the empty string.

Comment: All right, thank you for pointing out this difference. I did not expect that such constructs would be that much of a problem in bash / shell in general.